# A way to use iPad as a sketching device during presentations (without cables)?

Tags: ipad, mac

I would like to use an iPad as a sketch board during some presentations. Idea is quite simple. I draw on the iPad and the people can watch it on the big screen. One way to do it its plain simple. Just connect a HDMI cable to the iPad from the projector and you're set. You can use any app you prefer for that.

The problem arises if you want to get rid of the cables. I do have a Mac, which can be connected to the projector, but where to go from there?

I would imagine to use the Mac as some sort of the Airplay receiver, but then again one would still need a special sketching app, which supports this setup. Or is there a native way to clone iPad screen over to the Mac?

Any help and ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have your presentation or document you want to show on your Mac. If so, the setup I use is as follows:

1. Install [AirDisplay](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display) on your iPad and its client on your Mac
2. Install [CocoPad](http://projects.digitalwaters.net/index.php?q=cocopad) on your mac.
3. Using AirDisplay "link" your iPad to your mac and mirror the displays.
4. Connect your projector and mirror the display
5. Create a new document in CocoPad and in the right corner choose a "transparent" canvas.
6. Bring the  transparent canvas on top of the document you want to scribble on and then scribble with your finger (or a stylus) on the iPad

Since AirDisplay relies on a wireless network to become an external display, you may want to make your setup more reliable by creating your own wireless network. To do so go to System Preferences-> Sharing -> Internet Sharing and enable it. Connect your iPad to the "created" wireless network and the connection will now be rock solid.

Another option that you could try out is [inklet](http://www.tenonedesign.com/inklet.php) with cocoPad but it is a bit more expensive but with that option you would not need an iPad.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. AirDisplay solves the problem. CocoPad lacks some features like easier color swap, but in the end it will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I currently know is not available yet: With iOS 5 you will gain the ability to wirelessly mirror your iPad's display to an AppleTV.